# Eclipse suddenly stopped letting me modify variables in a Java project folder after an erroneous key command

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working a smallish Java project and I was attempting to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Instead of 'F' I think I hit 'G' and now it will not let me modify any variable. I can't change the text on buttons or assign values to 'int's. It gives me different error messages depending on where I am in the code. The problem only affects the Java project folder. I tried to replicate the error on another test class in a different folder but could not.

I copied all of my classes, deleted the project and remade it, copy and pasted the code back in and the problem persist. The code still runs fine but I cannot continue my work.

Does anyone have any clue?

UPDATE: I have now copied the code text into text files, sent them to another computer where Eclipse def works with no issues, recreated the project and class files, pasted the code in, AND STILL THE PROBLEM PERSIST. This makes me believe that somehow, someway, I have altered the code without realizing it, thus causing this issue, but I have looked it up and down and cannot find it.

Screenshots of simple example: [before](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjcebvwgcnfa4ep/before.png) and [after](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tssvjprimofyof2/after.png).

I really don't understand what the error in my code could be but I feel like I have eliminated any other possibility. Here it is if anyone could review it. [Helper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/829bviygb7vp12s/MessagePanel.java) and [Main](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkg7pijrdmb2u1j/MessageFrame.java)

Comment: are you sure you are not trying to edit the `class` files?

Comment: Umm, I don't think so. I didn't even know that eclipse would display the class files. I am definitely in the regular java file. I'll upload a screen shot.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Syntax error on ";" ,, expected - Is the one I get on the super simple example from the screenshots I just posted, but it changes on whatever I attempt to add. Usually something about a Syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign to a field variable in the class definition. This is only possible once when declaring a field, like `int r = 0`. After that, fields can only be assigned to in methods.

Comment: God, I'm so stupid. I just spent an hour trying to figure this out. Thank you, I was about to give up.

Answer (score 1):

When eclipse starts bugging me with some hair-pulling issues, as a last final resort, I re-create the workspace folder.

1. Goto the folder where workspace is on the directory
2. Delete the *.metadata* folder
3. Open eclipse and point the workspace in the same folder ( the projects wont load up yet )
4. Right click -> import existing projects -> and add all your projects again.

Comment: Wow, I was sure your suggestion was going to work. This is insane, it will let me say, `int n = 0;` and then cause an error when I say `n = 5;`. I mean this is crazy! I'm going to go to my other computer and see if this continues.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> is used for searching references in the workspace. It does not do any harm. Try to reopen eclipse. Sometimes this helps.

Comment: I know, looked it up afterwards. I reopened eclipse to no avail and cleaned the folder.